# Div circular dividido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css, css3

Me pidieron un trabajo en el cual hay una área donde se muestra ciertas notificaciones, el diseño es mas o menos así, el circulo se va ir coloreando dependiendo del proceso en el que se encuentre el usuario (los estados los controlo desde la base de datos), pero no se como hacerlo, alguna recomendación o herramienta para esto?

[image]

Comment: Hola, qué es lo que no sabes hacer? el css? el js? una imagen? Si lo que necesitas js seria algo asi? http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

Comment: ¿que necesitas?, ¿solo los estilos?.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el usuario no muestra ningún avance en el trabajo que le pidieron.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu codigo actual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es ponerle un `border-width` que sea la mitad del tamaño de tu círculo y elegir los cuatro colores que quieras para tu círculo.

Una vez hecho esto, y como se te verán en forma de "reloj de arena", tendrás que usar la función `transform: rotate(45)` para rotar el círculo 45 grados.

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo:

```css
#circulo{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: box-shadow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple orange blue green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#texto1{
   margin-left: -80px;
}

#texto2{
   top: -65px;
   left: -15px;
}

#texto3{
  left: -30px;
  top: 50px;
}

#texto4{
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo">
  <span id="texto1">Texto 1</span>
  <span id="texto2">Texto 2</span>
  <span id="texto3">Texto 3</span>
  <span id="texto4">Texto 4</span>
</div>
```

Para poner los textos en relación al círculo puedes posicionar el círculo mediante `position: relative;` y cada uno de los textos posicionarlos con `position: absolute;` para que tomen como referencia este círculo (para posicionarlos podrás usar las propiedades `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`).

Comment: +1. Esta respuesta también está buena pero en este caso como quedaría el texto dentro de cada cuadrante?

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Estoy realizando un edit ahora mismo para mostrarlo. Dame unos minutos para actualizar la respuesta :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un `div` para cada cuarto de círculo, algo parecido a esto:

```css
 .cuarto {
  position absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
 }
 #cuarto1{
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
 }
 #cuarto2{
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
 }
 #cuarto3{
  background-color:green;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  clear:both;
 }
 #cuarto4{
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="cuarto1" class="cuarto"></div>
<div id="cuarto2" class="cuarto"></div>
<div id="cuarto3" class="cuarto"></div>
<div id="cuarto4" class="cuarto"></div>
```

Para colocar el texto, puedes usar otro div y colocarlo donde creas conveniente, o jugar con los paddings.
Algo parecido a esto:

```css
 .cuarto {
  position absolute;
  width:67px;
  height:67px;
  float:left;
 }
 #cuarto1{
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  padding: 33px 0px 0px 33px;
 }
 #cuarto2{
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  padding: 33px 33px 0px 0px;
 }
 #cuarto3{
  background-color:green;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  padding: 16px 0px 17px 33px;
  clear:both;
 }
 #cuarto4{
  background-color:yellow;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
  padding: 16px 33px 17px 0px;  
 }
```

```html
<div id="cuarto1" class="cuarto">CV visto</div>
<div id="cuarto2" class="cuarto">Contratación</div>
<div id="cuarto3" class="cuarto">Entrevista</div>
<div id="cuarto4" class="cuarto">Entrega de papeles</div>
```

Comment: +1, solo como duda, si le agregas texto como queda?

Comment: Sin tocar nada, en la esquina superior izquierda, fuera del cuarto, usando otro div para el texto dentro de cada cuarto, lo puedes recolocar donde convenga..

Comment: +1, si pudieras agregar al ejemplo el texto de @Roberto? para ver como queda y a la vez para que el sepa como ubicarlo

Answer (score 0):

> con esto te servirá:

```css
.box-container{
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box01,.box02,.box03,.box04{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
}
.box01{
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.box02{
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.box03{
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.box04{
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box01"> content </div>
  <div class="box02"> content </div>
  <div class="box03"> content </div>
  <div class="box04"> content </div>
</div>
```